# Running shell script in rails only outputs the 1 line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bash, shell

I'm trying to make a rails controller pull the latest content from a repo on bit bucket. To the most part this is a success the only issue I have whilst testing I can only seem to get the page to output the first line the script returns and that seems to not run the rest of the script any ideas

Here is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash -l
GIT_REPO='IMAREPO'
TMP_GIT_CLONE=TEMPPATH
PUBLIC_WWW=SITEPATH

if [ -d $TMP_GIT_CLONE ]; then
   rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
fi
git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
jekyll build --source $TMP_GIT_CLONE --destination $PUBLIC_WWW
rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
exit
```

and in the rails controller I am doing

```
@result = %x[/var/srv/pulldevelopment.sh]
```

Which in turn only out put a single line from the script which is

> Cloning into '/root/tmp/git/blah'...

Comment: Is there anything in that script that outputs to stderr instead of stdout? Maybe you need something like `%x[script.sh 2>&1]`

Comment: Thanks that help actually find the problem (yet to fix it however) It seems that jekyll is trying to run under rails causing some gem issues and "invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII Error" in my markdown files..

is there a way to not run the jekyll under my rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. By default Git only prints progress status if stderr is connected to a TTY. You can reproduce this behavior in a terminal with:

```
$ git clone $GIT_REPO 2>&1 | cat
```

Pass `--progress` to always get progress status on the stderr stream. See [git-clone(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html).